# How to run 2 .java classes in order? (Selenium with Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, class, webdriver

I'm learning to use Selenium with Java, using Eclipse.

I want to know if there is a way to make 2 .java classes and run them in order?

For example:

> Class-1 is the Login page, this should execute first once I
>   start (Run) the Java Project.
>
> Class-2 is "go to X section of the webpage and do Y stuff", this
>   should go after the login since I need to be logged in the page to do it, so it
>   should execute automatically once the Class-1 is finish.

Is there a way to do it? Hope I explained myself correctly, I don't have a perfect english.
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use inheritance to achieve this? Also, you can achieve same with single class but different methods

Comment: I thought about it, doing inheritance, but my idea is to have everything seperated by classes, so I can just go and execute the one I need whitout having to modify it, and at the same time if I want to do multiple things at once I can just execute the ones I need, do you get me? being able to order them as I please. I do this because the people that will work with this want it the simplest way possible and I can't think in something else, I'm stuck... again sry for my bad english.

Comment: what about reusability in such case you will repeat same code again in both the classes if functionality is common

Answer (score 0):

You should use testing framework like TestNG to meet your needs. It has functionalities that make it more powerful and easier to use, such as:

- Annotations.
- Run your tests in arbitrarily big thread pools with various policies available (all methods in their own thread, one thread per test class, etc...).
- Test that your code is multithread safe.
- Flexible test configuration.
- Support for data-driven testing (with @DataProvider).
- Support for parameters.
- Powerful execution model (no more TestSuite).
  Supported by a variety of tools and plug-ins (Eclipse, IDEA, Maven, etc...).
- Embeds BeanShell for further flexibility.
- Default JDK functions for runtime and logging (no dependencies).
- Dependent methods for application server testing

`You can configure sequence or parallel execution of tests, include or exclude tests from multiple classes, configure test methods dependency on one another, enable or disable tests etc.`

See [TestNG Documentation](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html).